# The dragons of the world disappeared. Now what?

Tags: magic, politics, dragons

With nearly every major event in the world, the dragons were there. The world was built upon the backs of dragons and in turn, the dragons were revered by most mortal groups. In the southern half of the world, entire tribes of people grew to worship them religiously. Armies went to war for the dragons and *gladly* died for them. Imagine the dragons disappearing like if suddenly there were no people, and the animals took over. How would a society be affected when they are gone?

Comment: Questions asking "What would be the effect of X on the world?" are too broad for this site. Additionally we know nothing about your specific world, or your dragon, so if this question was a good fit we'd need more information for us to be able to answer it.